# How to install "tabto" macro?

Tags: installing, texlive, tabto

I am trying to install the "tabto.sty" and I am using the vanilla TeXLive from CTAN.

The tabto macro is archived in the CTAN at the following directory --

```
1. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabto
```

but my TeXLive repository is looking for it in this location --

```
2. http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

and it does not contain tabto.

I know that I can directly download the sty file (or zip archive) from the CTAN url (link 1 above) and use it. But I do not want to do that.

How do I make my TeXLive to fetch all required stuffs from both of the above URLs? Is there any "tlnet" compatible link for the CTAN repository (link 1) that I could use with tlmgr ?

Comment: I think you just want `tlmgr update tabto-ltx`

Comment: @David Carlisle: it's not working, I am having this message --

`tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: tabto-ltx mentioned, but neither new nor forcibly removed
tlmgr: no updates available`

Comment: what does `kpsewhich tabto.sty` return?

Comment: @David Carlisle: it returns nothing.

Comment: sorry then I give up, others here know more about how tlmgr works internally.  You could try `install` instead of `update`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find the TeX Live packages that contain a particular file (for example `tabto.sty`), you may use the following command:

```
% tlmgr search --global --file tabto.sty
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tabto-ltx:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabto-ltx/tabto.sty
```

Now, you know the name of the TeX Live package to install. You may install it with the following command:

```
% tlmgr install tabto-ltx
```

Comment: cool, this is what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 6):

The TeX Live package names are not always the same as the names of the LaTeX packages they contain. In this case you want `tabto-ltx`.

```
$ tlmgr info tabto
tlmgr: package repository http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: cannot find package tabto
```

nothing:-) But:

```
$ tlmgr info tabto-ltx
package:     tabto-ltx
category:    Package
shortdesc:   "Tab" to a measured position in the line.
longdesc:    \tabto{<length>} moves the typesetting position to <length> from the left margin of the paragraph. If the typesetting position is already further along, \tabto starts a new line; the command \tabto* will move position backwards if necessary, so that previous text may be overwritten. The command \TabPositions may be used to define a set of tabbing positions, after which the command \tab advances typesetting position to the next defined 'tab stop'.
installed:   Yes
revision:    30710
sizes:       doc: 121k, run: 9k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 1.3
cat-date:    2013-05-25 17:03:59 +0200
cat-license: lppl
collection:  collection-latexextra
```

Comment: hmm, I see, it's actually in the collection-latexextra. But it's big as well, and `install` did actually solved it!